# Swift 2: Issue when initializing a UIActivityViewController in Swift: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift2

I dont' understand why the following code I've used to initialize a `UIActivityViewController` causes the error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

```
    let shareText = "..."
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")

    let shareObjects = [shareText, url] // Compiler error happens here.
    let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareObjects, applicationActivities: nil)
```

Array of objects clearly contains a `String`, and a `NSURL`. An array literal that contains both of these surely should, by intuition, anyway, assume the lowest common type (like a nearest common ancestor of sorts) `[AnyObject]`.

Force downcasting doesn't work either: i.e. saying `let shareObjects = [shareText, url] as! [AnyObject]` doesn't make the error go away.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I just found out why.

NSURL's `init` is failable, which makes the `url` variable actually an optional.

`shareText` isn't an optional.

Sticking `shareText`, a non-optional, with `url`, an optional, together into an array causes the error.

The solution is to make sure the url is non-optional.